# How to use PanelColorSettings in custom Gutenberg block?

Tags: plugin-development, customization, block-editor

I'm working on a custom Gutenberg block. I have used `<PanelBody>` `<BaseControl>` and `<ColorPalette>` to create some custom color pickers, however, it seems like it would be more efficient to use the built-in `<PanelColorSettings>` component.

Has anyone used `<PanelColorSettings>` component in a custom block? The only discussion of this technique I could find was here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50480454/add-the-inbuilt-colour-palette-for-gutenberg-custom-block

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First you need to import the component -

```
const {
    PanelColorSettings,
} = wp.editor;
```

then inside the **InspectorControls** you call the component

```
<PanelColorSettings
                    title={ __( 'Color Settings' ) }
                    colorSettings={ [
                        {
                            value: color,
                            onChange: ( colorValue ) => setAttributes( { color: colorValue } ),
                            label: __( 'Background Color' ),
                        },
                        {
                            value: textColor,
                            onChange: ( colorValue ) => setAttributes( { textColor: colorValue } ),
                            label: __( 'Text Color' ),
                        },
                    ] }
                >

</PanelColorSettings>
```

Comment: Have you figured out how to generate classes with the colours names just like the core blocks do? I can't seem to replicate them :S

Comment: You have to use the color classes, Gutenberg handbook has them documented

Answer (score 2):

```
<PanelColorSettings
  title={__('Color Settings')}
  colorSettings={[
    {
      value: props.attributes.backgroundColor,
      onChange: (color) => props.setAttributes({ backgroundColor: color }),
      label: __('Background Color')
    },
    {
      value: props.attributes.textColor,
      onChange: (color) => props.setAttributes({ textColor: color }),
      label: __('Text Color'),
      colors: [
        {
          name: 'white',
          color: '#fff'
        },
        {
          name: 'black',
          color: '#222'
        }
      ]
    }
  ]}
/>
```